# C# Not all paths return a value

Tags: c#

When I keep my mouse over DownloadFile it says (not all paths return a value). What do I need to do to fix this?

```
public Stream DownloadFile()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("GAPDB"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileUpload FROM [FirmWareVersion]", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                 byte[] data = (byte[])reader["FileUpload"];
                 System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add else condition with return something or `null`

Comment: The compiler error is pretty clear: Not even do not all paths return a value, not a _single_ path returns a value! So, in your if block add a `return ms;` and probably a `return null;` at the end of your method.

Comment: you define a function that return a Stream. But in the function you does not return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a `Stream` as your method defines a `Stream` as a return type:

```
public Stream DownloadFile()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("GAPDB"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileUpload FROM [FirmWareVersion]", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                 byte[] data = (byte[])reader["FileUpload"];
                 System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                 return ms;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Alternatively you could mark your method as `void` if you do not need to return from it.