# How to fix : CS0161 'MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()': not all code paths return a value?

Tags: c#, maui, net6.0-android

How to fix this :

> CS0161    'MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp()': not all code paths return a
> value

I dont see what i'm doing wrong, can you please assist? Thank you!

PS: Im on realy begining level so Im sorry if I didnt seen solution that can be very simple but Im to stupid right now to solve it by myself.

```
namespace LoginApp;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
    }
}
```

I was searching on other forums etc. but I didint found answear for my porblem.

Comment: You are missing `return builder.Build();` at the end of that method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Not all paths return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275867/c-sharp-not-all-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: In my case, if miss the ```return builder.Build()```, a red wavy line appears under the ```CreateMauiApp()``` method

Answer (score 1):

in C# if a method has a non-void **return type** it means that the method must **return** an instance of that type.

Which in this case:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
```

It is of type `MauiApp`.  If you look at the default `CreateMauiApp` method created by the template, the last line is

```
return builder.Build();
```